# ASP.NET Unit Test DirectoryNotFoundException

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am trying to get a ASP.NET Unit Test running and I keep getting a DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find part of the Path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebsiteName\GPS\web.config.  The problem is the path to the GPS web.config is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebsiteName\website\GPS\web.config.  I can't figure out how to set the path of this web.config.  My attributes are posted below.  As you can see the logical convention seems to be what the test is looking for, but our Website is just not set up like that.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [HostType("ASP.NET")]
    [UrlToTest("http://localhost/WebsiteName/GPS/Default.aspx")]
    [DeploymentItem("GPS.dll")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you change the UrlToTest attribute parameter to
http://localhost/WebsiteName/website/GPS/Default.aspx?

Comment: It doesn't work because the actual website url is http://localhost/WebsiteName/GPS/Default.aspx.